# How to check if GUI application is running on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, qt, selenium

I have a GUI app, that was written with c++ and QT and I have UI tests with selenium + qtwebdriver. my bash script launches app and then launches python tests. The problem is, if I write this:

```
./myapp
python mypythonscript.py
```

Python script will fail because, "myapp" need 2 seconds to open interface.
What can I do to find out, if GUI app is completely running ? Is there any command to X server, that can return name of launched windows ?

Comment: You can add pause/sleep after the first line for 5 seconds `sleep 5`, or you can check the running processes by using `ps` and `grep`

Comment: yeah, I know this way to add sleep, but what will happen if app will be launching for 12 seconds ? I am looking for universal solution.

Comment: take a look at this  `https://askubuntu.com/a/157787/791238`

Comment: @Stack 
hey, thanks for your answer. 
pgrep will show, that the process is running, even if GUI have not appeared yet. I need to detect if GUI is showed up.

Comment: Your app 'knows' when its GUI is visible: Override your main widget's `resizeEvent()`. There you could use some type of inter-process communication (e.g. create / update a specific temp file) which you wait on in your launcher.

Comment: I stand corrected: `resizeEvent()` alone is not sufficient, `showEvent()` is better suited.

Comment: @MartinHennings 
hey, I need to do this without changing application code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your script to sleep for the necessary seconds. Then you could use nvidia-smi to check what the GPU has in memory...

```
watch -n1 nvidia-smi
```